# Clipping mask via css, canvas or svg for div

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have full-width div on page.

```
<div style="background: red"></div>
```

Bottom should be waved

[waved example](https://sasulca447b.mail.yandex.net/rdisk/f47fb8205f307fc26a9ca3ac9eaa361f/mpfs/n9PpdsEYZ9N9c-sdrGL6R0ESkBhwGM3NYcvC6VlSbDg1pmkJS7ilFcs18jsAKZ2M6BUeOP53JIKDEeX1ZvepTA==?uid=0&filename=2014-04-16%2014-05-16%2002_about_fullhd.psd%20-%20IrfanView.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&rtoken=4bd09f6abf52252525884f1260d76ab1&rtimestamp=534e5829)

Also should have different colors

[another color](http://yadi.sk/d/ZMeBzCbuMZ6KD)

Is there any way without creating all variants of bottom images, to implement this>?

Comment: Could you use a background image for the wave effect and change the background color for the rest of it? or does the wave change color too?

Comment: No i cant, because parent div or page body may have background-image